# Get dataset from .net webservice and set it on android gridview

Tags: android, json, gridview, dataset

I am calling wcf restful webservices from android application.I am successfully posting data to webservice and receiving response from webservice using JSON Object.

Now I need to show data(dataset) received from webservice,on my android application in gridview.

Please help me by providing some tutorials or links to do the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you already have a REST(JSON) you can use a JSONObject.

You get the json from the REST and load it into JSONObject and then take the JSONObject and convert it into a specific object.  And then take the list of object and bind it.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

[Tutorial](http://www.androidsnippets.com/retrieve-json-from-a-rest-web-service)

```
  JSONObject obj = "From REST Request"

    try {

    JSONArray users = obj.getJSONArray("users");

    for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {

        User user = new User(users.getJSONObject(i));           
    }

    } catch (JSONException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    }


class User {
private String _username;
private String _displayName;

public User() {

}

public User(JSONObject obj) {

    if (obj == null)
    return;

    try {

    setUsername(obj.getString("username"));
    setDisplayName(obj.getString("displayname"));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public String getUsername() {
    return _username;
}

public void setUsername(String _username) {
    this._username = _username;
}

public String getDisplayName() {
    return _displayName;
}

public void setDisplayName(String _displayName) {
    this._displayName = _displayName;
}
}
```

Comment: :thanks for replying but for the webservice i will get a dataset in the form of json object.The number of columns will be 7 and i want to show all data in the form of grid on android.So please guide me how to do this ??